# How to find UID of an app installed on Android and use it as a shell user?

Tags: file-system, shell, terminal, ssh

I am trying to find a way to determine the user name of the current shell user from within a shell / terminal on an Android device.

The Android environment that I have in `/system/bin` and `/system/xbin` does not have the unix `user` command. Overall, it appears that the concept doesn't quite exist on Android, but at least, on my rooted device, there is a user `root` and also there are groups such as `shell` and `everybody`, based on the permissions of files on the system.

The background is the following:
I want to run an `ssh` command (I installed a version of OpenSSH also) on the Android that uses a local `private key`. The key has file permissions and those are required to be restrictive by OpenSSH for good reason (the UNIX group of the file should not have permissions to access the key, only the owner).

Since I know only the user `root`, I can set the owner of the key to `root` and run `ssh` as root. However, I don't really want to run `ssh` as root.

I am issuing the shell command from within `Automate` which has that option. Apparently, it's possible to execute the command without root permissions. However, if I add the key file to the `ssh` command, it can't get access to the file that is accessible only by `root`. Thus I would like to set the owner in the UNIX file permissions of the key to the shell user used by `Automate`, but I do not know how to find out who that is.

**EDIT:**

```
~# grep automate /data/system/packages.list
com.llamalab.automate 10106 0 /data/user/0/com.llamalab.automate default:targetSdkVersion=24 3002,3003,3001
```

I assume `10106` is the UID, but is that a static value? If yes, could I add a line to `/etc/passwd` by using `adduser` command from busybox or Termux?

Answer (score 3):

Android inherits from Linux the concept of `shell`, which is the core component of Linux login process. But there is no concept of `Linux console login` on Android <sup>([1](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209053/218526))</sup> because it boots directly to GUI. However it makes use of Discretionary Access Control (DAC) of Linux kernel which is based on UIDs / GIDs and permission mode. Every installed app is considers as a *NIX user and is assigned a unique UID at install time. See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208982/218526) for more details on this.
You can get UID of `Automate` app from file `/data/system/packages.list` or by executing `id -u` from within app:

```
~# awk '/^com.llamalab.automate/ {print $2}' /data/system/packages.list
10106
```

Since you want a remote login from local machine using a `ssh` binary (built from standard Linux source) which is to be executed by `Automate` app i.e. with UID 10106, the `key` file must also be owned by UID 10106. The only place on device which is owned by UID 10106 is the directory `/data/data/com.llamalab.automate`, so this should be set as `$HOME` for `ssh` and where the `key` should be placed under directory `.ssh` owned by UID/GID 10106:

```
~# mkdir /data/data/com.llamalab.automate/.ssh
~# ssh-keygen -f /data/data/com.llamalab.automate/.ssh/id_rsa
~# chmod 0700 /data/data/com.llamalab.automate/.ssh
~# chown -R 10106.10106 /data/data/com.llamalab.automate/.ssh
```

Create file `/etc/passwd` with a single line: `user:x:10106:10106::/data/data/com.llamalab.automate:/system/bin/sh` where `user` is any username of your choice. You can also use `adduser`:

```
~# touch /etc/passwd
~# busybox adduser -D -H -h /data/data/com.llamalab.automate -s /system/bin/sh -u 10106 user
```

Also add `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to `ssh` command so that new server is added to `known_hosts` without user interaction.

However if the `ssh` binary is built specifically for Android to be used with an app, it must have its `$HOME` already hard-coded which can't be changed using `/etc/passwd`. In this case you can try something like `ssh -i <path/to/key> -o UserKnownHostsFile=<path/to/known_hosts> <user>@<IP>`. Permissions must be set and both paths must be accessible by executing app.

**PS:**

Please note that UID 10106 must be member of group `aid_inet` (GID 3003) for `ssh` to be able to make connections. All apps with `android.permission.INTERNET` are member of this group. Or you can add a line to `/etc/group`: `internet:x:3003:user`. Or using `addgroup`:

```
~# touch /etc/group
~# busybox addgroup -g 3003 internet
~# busybox addgroup user internet
```

However this is useful only for programs which perform login (`setgroups()`) like `su`, `sshd` etc.

For more details on how Android lacks Linux's login mechanism, see [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209919/218526).