# How to run a program in an app context with Magisk?

Tags: root-access, permissions, selinux

Let's say I'm currently as root in Bash on a terminal, outside any app like Termux. I'm running Magisk.

Now I want to synchronously invoke Termux's Bash, such that it behaves the same way as it would if I had directly started the Termux app (i.e. with the same permissions and SELinux context and user/group and everything else).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Android framework takes care of a lot of things when forking an app from `zygote`. In short, it's nearly impossible to run an app process from commandline so that it behaves *“exactly the same way”* as if the app was properly launched. Continue reading to have an idea of why it's so.

In order to run `bash` in Termux app's context so that it behaves exactly the same way as if it was started from the app, it must be run at least:

- With UID/GID of the app assigned by the Package Manager at the time of installation
- With supplementary group `inet` (`3003`), which is required to create network sockets and is assigned to any app at the time of installation which declares `android.permission.INTERNET` in its *AndroidManifest.xml*. For details see [How Android's permissions mapping with UIDs/GIDs works?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/208523/218526).
- With supplementary group `everybody` (`9997`) which is used to control app's read / write access to `/sdcard`. For details see [What is the “u#_everybody” UID?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/210159/218526).
- With supplementary groups `<uid>_cache` (UID+10000) and `all_<uid>` (UID+40000) so that app can access its cache, native executable code etc. But these aren't required necessarily since we are not running the app itself.
- By entering the mount namespace of Termux app (`com.termux` process) which is required for supgid `9997` to work. If the app isn't running (e.g. if running from `adb shell`), supgid `1015` can be used to get write access to `/sdcard` but that's not how the app works.
- By dropping all Linux [capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) (granular root privileges in *Effective*, *Permitted*, *Inheritable*, *Bounding* and *Ambient* sets) as well as setting `securebits` and process control attribute *NO_NEW_PRIVS* which make sure that app isn't able to elevate privileges by making use of `setuid` or file capabilities.
- With blocked `syscalls` by applying [seccomp-bpf](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/07/seccomp-filter-in-android-o.html) filter.
- With SELinux context of the app, which is determined at install / runtime based on MMAC <sup>([1](https://selinuxproject.org/page/NB_SEforAndroid_1#Install.2FRun-time_MMAC_Policy), [2](https://hsc.com/Blog/Combating-Android-Security-Issues-The-Case-for-Hardening-Android-1))</sup>.
- By adding the process to relevant [cgroups](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html) e.g. `cpuset`, `memcg` etc. as the Android's framework does.
- By *catching*, *blocking* and *ignoring* the same [signals](http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~holzmann/C/system/signals.html) as the app would do.
- By setting the environment it relies on. E.g. Termux's bash won't execute without `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which it requires for dynamic linking.

There isn't a single commandline tool available which can do all of this sandboxing, it can be achieved fully only programmatically (see [Minijail](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/minijail)), or might be using multiple tools e.g. `nsjail`/`firejail` for setting `seccomp` filters, `runcon` to change SELinux context, `capsh` to alter DAC/capabilities, `nsenter` to enter mount namespace etc. [`setpriv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setpriv.1.html) from `util-linux` package can do the maximum:

```
~# uid=$(stat -c %u /data/data/com.termux)
~# pid=$(pidof -s com.termux)
~# label=$(cat /proc/$pid/attr/current)
~# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib
~# exec nsenter -t $pid -m setpriv --reuid $uid --regid $uid --groups 3003,9997 --bounding-set -all --selinux-label $label -- /system/bin/sh -c 'exec /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash'
```

<sup>* `nsenter` and `setpriv` are busybox applets but with limited functionality. For `aarch64` you may get static binaries here: [nsenter](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=1899786940962595054), [setpriv](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=1899786940962595056).</sup>

However we need to define `shell_exec` (label of `/system/bin/sh`) as [`entrypoint`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/chap-security-enhanced_linux-selinux_contexts#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-SELinux_Contexts-Domain_Transitions) for execution by `untrusted_app` context which is not part of stock `sepolicy` (at least on Pie):

```
~# supolicy --live 'allow untrusted_app shell_exec file entrypoint'
```

Executing `/system/bin/sh` before executing `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash` is required because `/data` partition is mounted with `nosuid` option which prevents SELinux context transition (from `magisk` to `untrusted_app`) <sup>([3](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/FAQ#Applications_do_not_transition_on_a_nosuid-mounted_partition))</sup> and you get permission denied. You may consider mounting `/data` without `nosuid` to skip this step.
For the same reason `--no-new-privs` and `--selinux-label` can't be used in conjunction.

All this happens in native world, nothing in Java stack. So we have no direct control on things like [manifest permissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission) which entirely operate inside Android framework. However manifest permission enforcement is also based on UIDs <sup>([4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/core/java/android/content/PermissionChecker.java#78))</sup>. For instance if Termux was granted `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` the bash we are running with Termux's UID will also be able to write to `/sdcard`.

---

From your comment:

> It doesn't make sense to me how this is possible. Like, consider the output:
>
> ```
> u0_a129 ~$ /sbin/su --context=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 u0_a129 -c /system/bin/id
> uid=10129(u0_a129) gid=10129(u0_a129) groups=10129(u0_a129) context=u:r:magisk:s0
> u0_a129 ~$ /system/bin/id
> uid=10129(u0_a129) gid=10129(u0_a129) groups=10129(u0_a129),3003(inet),9997(everybody),20129(u0_a129_cache),50129(all_a129),99909997(u999_everybody) context=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768
> ```

Well, according to my understanding that's how Unix Discretionary Access Control works. First of all passing `--context` to Magisk's `/sbin/su` makes no difference as explained [here](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/blob/v19.4/docs/tools.md):

> the option still exists for CLI compatibility with apps designed for SuperSU. However the option is silently ignored since it's no longer relevant.

So the context isn't switched as you can see it's still `u:r:magisk:s0`. Secondly Magisk's `su` isn't the actual switch user <sup>([5](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/issues/1463#issuecomment-506874581))</sup>, it provides a minimal functionality of standard `su` binary (the one we have on Linux). For details see [How Magisk works?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213344/218526)

In your first command it set UID, GID and supplementary groups to the UID you provided. You didn't ask `su` to set any additional supplementary groups, neither it can.

In second command you see the UID, GID, supplementary groups and SELinxu context which were set by `zygote` when it forked the app's DVM/ART (`com.termux` in case of Termux). Supplementary groups are explained above. `99909997` is also explained in the [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/210159/218526) given above.

Comment: It would be nice (hint, hint!) if the `termux` developers would build some sort of cli-callable utility to perform all of these functions, so that we can write commands that utilize `termux` capabilities for Magisk, adb, and other utilities. And note that `termux-boot` does not apparently run with all of these conventions, and programs initiated via `termux-boot` fail -- even on my rooted device -- because one or more of these necessary capaibilites are not set when the boot scripts run.
IMHO, `termux` would be much more useful if such a `termux` helper program was available.

Comment: @HippoMan taking care of all of these prerequisites and sandboxing mechanisms (plus those I don't know of or missed) is not the responsibility of app developers, neither they can. It's the Android framework which fulfills all of these requirements when forking an app from `zygote`. Incorporating these functionalities in an app or a separate utility would be equivalent to including a reasonably large part of AOSP code in them. This answer is just a reference to have an idea of what things are taken care of when launching an app. In actual there are even more complications involved.

Comment: For Linux distros, there are `--reuid`, `--regid`, `--groups`, etc. available for `setpriv`; but I get `setpriv: unrecognized option '--groups'` in Android. Duh. Maybe there is something missing, or I'm using a wrong BusyBox. Maybe I must compile the tool myself. At last, `setpriv` does not work with the options mentioned.

Comment: @MAChitgarha I mentioned that bb applet is limited. And the static binary link is also given. Just checked it again for you: https://ibb.co/98nQ3g1

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks for your attention. My phone architecture is `arm`, not `aarch64`. Do the files work on my platform, or I should make them myself? If the later, please post the source code of the library I should compile. Thanks.

Comment: No. 64bit binary won't run on 32bit arch. `setpriv` is part of `util-linux` package: https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux

Comment: any other solution without using `setpriv` ? the latest `BusyBox v1.36.1-Magisk (2023-09-02 05:30:11 PDT)` `setpriv` ony support limited option.