# Is it possible to run comand as Termux after boot process?

Tags: boot, magisk, termux

I have set up a Node.js app. In order to automatically do all the things after the phone boot, I want to make a Magisk module to run a service. The command is `npm start` and exposes HTTP service on port 8000. The node app depends on many things on Termux, so is it possible to run that command as Termux?

Comment: [How to run a program in an app context with Magisk?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217104/218526)