# Why are superuser permissions needed to acess /data partition?

Tags: root-access, partitions

The default account is normal user, and I used it to install Google Play Store APK (to `/data`). Then Google Play Store was opened using my current user's permissions, and it is used to download and install other APKs to `/data`. That means I have full access to the `/data` partition.

Why are file manager apps unable to view that partition without root permissions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First to clarify only `root` (UID `0`) isn't enough to get access to `/data` at least since Android 5. Discretionary Access Control  based on traditional UNIX UIDs/GIDs alone doesn't fulfill the needs of modern complex OSes like Android. DAC is supplemented by Mandatory Access Control (MAC); SELinux in case of Android. So to access `/data` your process/user must have an allowed policy explicitly defined.

> Google Play Store was opened under my current user permission

This isn't correct. Concept of *“users”* is different on Android than on normal Linuxes. On Android every app is assigned a unique UID (from range 10000 to 19999) and it runs under its own user. Privileges are then controlled through Android's [permission framework](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218153/218526). At filesystem level every app is bound to a few directories (private and shared), that too subject to some permissions. For details see [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507/218526)

So there is no human user which could run its all programs under current user/UID.

> it downloaded and installed other APKs to /data. That means I have full access to the `/data` partition.

Play Store doesn't install `apk` files, it just performs a few verifications and downloads the file using Download Manager (`com.android.providers.downloads`) which runs under its own UID. App installation to `/data/app` and other relevant directories is mainly handled by **Package Manager** service running under UID `1000` (`system_server` process) in Java stack and **`installd`** running under UID `0` in native stack. **Package Installer** (`com.android.packageinstaller`) is the system app - running under its own UID - which provides user interface to (un)install apps manually. See more details [here](https://code4andy.blogspot.com/2014/01/android-package-manager-and-package.html). Similarly all apps and processes have their own SELinux contexts to allow access to required processes and files. There are a number of APIs and IPCs involved in this whole process.

> Why superuser permission is needed for accessing `/data` partition?

Simply put, it's protection. As you need root access to change `/etc` directory on Linux OSes and as you need Administrator rights to open Registry Editor on Windows. This restriction is to isolate and protect every app's process in a confined environment. Other than **DAC** and **MAC**, other phenomena like Linux **capabilities**, **namespaces**, **cgroups** and **seccomp** filters are also used for this [sandboxing](https://source.android.com/security/app-sandbox). It also enforces apps' limited access to resources and makes auditing easy.

A few common reasons from my answer to [How do I access `$HOME/storage` outside of Termux?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/218354/218526):

`/data` partition also contains system settings including sensitive data like password databases (though not saved as plain text), contacts, call logs and apps statistics. So `/data` isn't accessible without root in order to:

- Protect apps' private data from other apps
- Protect system data and settings from bad apps and malware
- Isolate users/profiles from other users/profiles
- Not let apps access shared storage without Storage permission granted
- Enforce APIs by Android framework so that apps can't use system resources and read/manipulate device information and settings without proper permissions

And possibly there are other reasons. For more details see [Are multiple-users protected from each other differently than apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213921/218526)

Comment: MAC is not needed to "fulfill the needs of modern complex OSes". It's a gratuitously more complex model for things that DAC/conventional unix permissions model could handle just fine. The purpose of MAC is impedance match with TLAs' mental model of access control, not any technical need.

Comment: @R.. my statement gives that impression? I said old traditional UNIX permission model used in 80's/90's isn't enough, that was designed to isolate human users, not processes. Some innovation is needed, whether that's capabilities or ACL's or MAC. I'm not an expert in security models but with my limited knowledge I don't have a strong reason to disagree with you. However it's an opinion and the opponents have strong arguments too.

Comment: @R @Ifran Latif.  So why the does  one app disappear after reboot after its linked to `/data/sdext2 partition`  & another app similarly linked with Exact same `DAC Octals & Selinux`  will survive a reboot. The disappearing app's `./app-lib  & ./data ` folders are there but their folders in `apk` have vanished in  `/data/sdext2 partition` . This is besides ... `/data/app/<disappeared app folder deleted here>`. When I link everything short of  the `apk`  it will remain & everything is fine. Why this behavior ( `magisk rooted android Q project Treble ROM ` )  ?

Comment: `seLinux` is `permissive`

Comment: because sdext2 is mounted too late