# How is it possible that I run android apps with the right user rights

Tags: security, linux, permissions, app-data

I learned for every app I installed on my Android, a new user is created. And the data for this app is stored in /data/data/app folder with the only access permission to the user that is created for the app. Then how can I access the data when I run the app as me (another user) . I want to be able to replicate the same behavior when I install apps on my Linux machine.

Comment: Yes every app is a unique UID on Android. App is stored to `/data/app`, data is stored to `/data/data`. You can't do that exactly on Linux machine because there human users are isolated, not programs. So every human user gets a unique UID but all apps/programs run by that user have same UID (unless you explicitly run them with different UID). See some related details in this answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213921/218526

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are superuser permissions needed to acess /data partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218569/why-are-superuser-permissions-needed-to-acess-data-partition)

Comment: Android is different to Linux, there is no account for you, only for each of your apps. And that you can't access the app-private data is part of the security concept. If you don't accept this you have to root your device.

Comment: If I read correctly, OP is asking is how to replicate the "one app, one user" scheme Android has, but on GNU/Linux. Kind of how programs like `cups` operate under a separate user and group. If that's the case, this question might be off-topic.