# How do I manipulate the filesystem of my Android smartphone from PC without restrictions? Can I do it on an non-rooted phone?

Tags: usb-debugging, file-transfer, usb-connection-mode, file-management, usb-drivers

I want to be able to copy/move/erase/modify files on my phone and transfer them back and forth on my Windows 10 PC. Without limitations hopefully.

My phone ( [Meizu Note 8](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32949916460.html) ) is not rooted, and I'm not sure if I can root it. It doesn't seem to be very popular.

I got the vague impression that I need ADB drivers which I also couldn't get, and I don't know what software to use after. [This](https://usbdriverspie.com/meizu-note-8/#Download_USB_Drivers_For_Meizu_Note_8) is the best I found, but it's far from official and also doesn't work: no installer, and the .inf doesn't have the install option in the context menu, which usually means the driver is not compatible.

Comment: What "limitations" are you talking about? If you are curious about ADB driver security you can use the one Google includes in it's Android SDK. For Windows you just have to modify the INF file(s) and add the USB ID of your device to it.

Comment: What filesystem you are talking about? You can access external shared storage (`/sdcard`) and mostly OS files (in `/system`, `/vendor`) from ADB shell or MTP. Also there are multiple alternatives to both of these native methods e.g. FTP: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91900. But you cannot access `/data` which holds a large part of OS configurations and apps data: [Why are superuser permissions needed to access /data partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218572/218526).

Comment: I wanted to save/manipulate app data. Seems rather inacessible.

Answer (score 0):

To access app data you must be rooted.

When rooted you can access the /data folder with adb. You do adb shell.
Then su to access superuser rights and then you can access /data.