# Can I access "/data/user/0/" folder in Android emulator from Ubuntu PC?

Tags: file-system, android-studio

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.
From Android Studio with the following code I am getting file directory

```
Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
final File filesDir = ctx.getFilesDir();
```

which is `/data/user/0/com.example.ipfs/files/`. I am running my app on Android Emulator. How do I go to the `/data/user/0/com.example.ipfs/files/` folder from my PC?

Comment: If your emulator runs `userdebug` ROM so that ADBD runs with root privileges, then simply do `adb root; adb shell ls /data/user/0/com.example.ipfs/files/`. If it's a final `user` build (usually the one with Play Services), then you first need to root your emulator ([MagiskOnEmulator](https://github.com/shakalaca/MagiskOnEmulator)). See [Why are superuser permissions needed to acess /data partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218572/218526) and [Why “adb root” does nothing?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213429/218526)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For this, Android Studio has the feature called ***Device File Explorer*** that will allow you to view the connected device or emulator internal files. This is useful especially when you are utilising the `getFilesDir()` as a path to save your app generated files & hence are not able to see them with the standard **File Manager**.

From the main menu, go to **View** -> **Tool Windows** -> **Device File Explorer**. You can then select your device / emulator from the drop down list.

To access `/data/user/0/com.example.ipfs/files/`, just go to the directory `data/data/com.example.ipfs/files` from the list displayed in the ***Device File Explorer*** once your device / simulator is connected.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 right now I tried this solution using AndroidStudio2022 and it's work and I figure out it was pointing to a hidden files below..

> PATH:
> /home/[user]/.cache/Google/AndroidStudio2022.1/device-explorer/[device_emulator_name]/data/user/0/[project_name]
>
> Example:
> /home/awen/.cache/Google/AndroidStudio2022.1/device-explorer/Pixel_5_API_32
> [emulator-5554]/data/user/0/com.example.html_pdf_demo