# How is an APK prevented from making security changes during their installation process

Tags: security, installation

What if the APK installation ran a few scripts? Overwrote files outside it's designated folder? Edited a few files? etc? What would prevent it from doing so?

Answer (score 3):

An APK does not have any control over its installation process. Installation is performed by the Android operating system. Details can be found in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218572/218526).

But once an app is installed, it can then run its code and try to make malicious changes.

> What would prevent it from doing so?

At Linux kernel level:

- DAC (UID, GID, mode)
- MAC (SELinux labels)

Read more about [Android app sandbox](https://source.android.com/security/app-sandbox).

At Android platform level:

- Manifest permissions
- AppOp permissions

Read more about permissions [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview), [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217522/218526) and [here](https://mirfatif.github.io/PermissionManagerX/help/help#perms_types).

**Related:**

- [Are multiple-users protected from each other differently than apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213921/218526)