# List of ADB settable permissions

Tags: permissions

I am searching for a list of permissions that can be set with adb.

I could just iterate through all permissions and ignore the failed ones but i'd rather filter out the ones that i know can't be set before hand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can grant or revoke only runtime permissions (introduced in Android 6 with [protection level](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217522/218526): `dangerous`) - either from CLI (`adb shell`) or GUI (Settings). From package manager help:

```
~$ pm
...
  grant [--user USER_ID] PACKAGE PERMISSION
  revoke [--user USER_ID] PACKAGE PERMISSION
    These commands either grant or revoke permissions to apps.  The permissions
    must be declared as used in the app's manifest, be runtime permissions
    (protection level dangerous), and the app targeting SDK greater than Lollipop MR1.
...
```

To get a list of all on-device `dangerous` permissions:

```
~$ pm list permissions -g -d | awk -F: '/permission:/ {print $2}'
```

Or get directly from Android source. This list excludes any dangerous permissions defined by non-AOSP packages e.g. those provided by Google Play Services. `wget` is a busybox applet, or get a static binary:

```
~$ wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/android-9.0.0_r52/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml | grep -E 'protectionLevel=|<permission android:name=' | grep -B1 'protectionLevel=.*dangerous' | awk -F'"' '/permission/ {print $2}'
```

Or to avoid any wrong results, pre-format `.xml` (you need to get `xmllint` or similar tool):

```
~$ wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/android-9.0.0_r52/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml | xmllint --format - | grep 'protectionLevel=.*dangerous' | grep -o 'permission android:name=[^ ]*' | cut -d'"' -f2
```

---

In addition to `dangerous` permissions, it's also possible to `grant` or `deny` or `ignore` some of the special permissions shown under:
**Settings → Apps & Notifications → Advanced → Special App Access**.
These are not managed directly by package manager, but `appops` - a secondary permissions control framework. These are `signature` level permissions which can be granted only to system apps otherwise. On Android 9:

```
~$ wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/android-9.0.0_r52/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml | grep -E 'protectionLevel=|<permission android:name=' | grep -B1 'protectionLevel=.*appop' | awk -F'"' '/permission/ {print $2}'
android.permission.MANAGE_IPSEC_TUNNELS
android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES
android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS
android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATIONS
android.permission.INSTANT_APP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE
```

Their corresponding `appops` operations have [similar names](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r52/core/java/android/app/AppOpsManager.java#910) with minor differences. Also some OPs [depend on](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r52/core/java/android/app/AppOpsManager.java#652) other OPs. To get a complete list of operations you can read or set through command-line:

```
~$ wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/android-9.0.0_r52/core/java/android/app/AppOpsManager.java | awk '/int OP_/ {print $5}'
```

For details on how to use `appops` see examples of [`VIBRATE`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215658/218526), [`REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216092/218526), [`COARSE_LOCATION`/`FINE_LOCATION`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218820/218526) and [`BOOT_COMPLETED`/`RUN_IN_BACKGROUND`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209345/218526).

Answer (score 5):

To get a list of all permissions available system-wide, use

`adb shell pm list permissions`

That will give you a full list of what permissions are available to be given/rejected on that device, including permissions defined by the manufacturer or by apps installed on the device.

To get a list of the permissions applicable to a specific app, use

`adb shell appops get <PackageName>`

That will give you a list of the permissions that that particular app may request, including whether or not the permission has been granted.

You can then use

`adb shell appops set <PackageName> <PermissionName> ignore`

or `adb shell appops set <PackageName> <PermissionName> allow`

to either deny or allow that permission for that app.