# how to stop google's phone app of being auto allowed to display over the apps?

Tags: settings, system-apps

i have a poco x3 nfc with arrowsOs android 11. I use google's vanilla phone app as my default phone app. I don't want to have a bubble when minimizing my phone app. for this, i go to app info > display over the other apps and disable it. but for some reason after some time (absurdly random periods, from seconds to hours) the app always returns to be allowed to display over the other apps. i would like to understand if this is mandatory or if it's optional, how can i disable it

Comment: Most probably you can't. GMS has extra [privileges](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218153/218526) that normal user apps don't have. They don't compromise on it. And they are capable of regaining the permissions denied by the user. Privacy preachings and user friendliness is only for others, not for Google itself. They totally take control of your device.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access, make Google Dialer a user app. Currently it is in system/priv-app.