# How is Google Assistant listening all the time without a notification?

Tags: privacy, microphone, google-assistant

In Android, if an app wants to run in the background, it usually needs to create a service that runs in the background (and/or after boot is completed). So, if the app wants to listen to the microphone all the time, it needs to run such a service from my understanding, and in the modern Android version, they are forced to create a notification and it needs to clearly specify what it does in the notification or it will violate [Play Stalkerware Policy](https://www.cnet.com/tech/mobile/google-stalkerware-policy-requires-apps-to-tell-users-theyre-installed-a-lot/) which Google Assistant does not show it.

How can this be allowed? Also, how can an app implement a microphone listener if Google Assistant is already running?

Comment: Running a foreground service is a requirement for third party user apps. Google apps are the [privileged ones](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218153/218526). They have exceptional capabilities. // A shameless self promotion: you can use the Pro version of my app [WhatsRunning](https://github.com/mirfatif/WhatsRunning) to conveniently view a long list of always-running apps and services in background. Google services are usually the highest in count.

Comment: Thank you @IrfanLatif, it looks very useful, and in my case, I wanted to add a voice commands functionality to my app that user can do some actions with their voice but it will need to listen to the mic all the time and this is not something comfortable by most of users