# What does it mean when a file is owned by the user “system” and the group “system”? in android file system

Tags: linux, file-system, aosp

I just trying to understand What does it mean when a file is owned by the user “system” and the group “system”? in the android file system.

In the android device file system

```
root@xyz:/ # ls -l cache/
drwxrwxr-x system   system            1969-12-31 17:00 SH_DIR
drwx------ system   system            2021-06-02 23:26 backup
drwxrwx--- root     root              2021-06-02 23:17 lost+found
drwxrwxrwx root     root              2021-06-08 02:12 test
drwxrwx--- system   cache             2021-06-07 05:40 recovery
```

For SH_DIR and backup have owned by the user “system” and the group “system”.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It means that the file is owned by UID `1000` and GID `1000` in [Discretionary access control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretionary_access_control). Getting familiar with DAC is usually the first step in the introduction of any Linux/UNIX based system, including MAC and even Windows (though with major differences in nomenclature). [This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208982/218526) of mine includes some details on Android's DAC. And [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213921/218526) a little more.

Comment: Very helpful link: [Unix File Permissions](https://docs.nersc.gov/filesystems/unix-file-permissions/). Originally commented by [Firelord](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/96277/firelord) :)