# Linux command 'w' - how is this as command written in Android shell?

Tags: command-line

I am searching for similiar commands in Android shell - as they are used in Linux like these commands - what can I type in Android terminal for :

> w
>
> who
>
> whoami

?

Thank you.

Comment: You need busybox ... You can get no root busy box from the play store.

Comment: Or copy it to /data/tmp/busybox and set the correct permissions

Comment: @Zillinium - busybox is available as package in termux ... wait ... there is only command wc and this hangs itself up !?

Comment: toybox (shipped with Android since Lollipop release) comes with `whoami`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux commands `w` and `who` read login information from file `/var/run/utmp`. Traditional Linux sysV login records/logs like [utmp](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utmp), `wtmp`, `btmp` and `lastlog` are set and read by some programs that make use of GNU libc (the most commonly used C library on Linux distros) and other libc's. These files contain information about currently and previously logged-in users.

However there is no concept of Linux console [login](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/sag.html#TERMINAL-LOGINS-TABLE) on Android as it isn't designed for multiple user logins. [Virtual terminals](https://linux.die.net/man/4/console) are disabled on Android by default, `init` doesn't start `getty`, and hence there is no [login](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/login.1.html), no login manager (like `logind`), no `shell` at startup and no user sessions, and therefore no login files. Android boots directly to GUI. Other CLI programs like `sshd` that read/write these login files are also not part of Android. So Android's Bionic libc neither provides the functions of [utmp.h](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/utmp.5.html), nor filesystem hierarchy contains `/var/log` or `/var/run`. However if a program linked against standard Linux libc's is used on Android, it will try to access these login files. But if a program - like `w`, `who`, `users`, `last` and `lastlog` - is totally dependent on these files, it simply won't work. You can use busybox such as [yashdsaraf's](https://github.com/yashdsaraf/bb-bot/releases) to get all these commands on Android.

Linux command `whoami` gets the (effective) UID of process by making syscall [geteuid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getuid.2.html) directly to kernel and then on Linux , if possible, resolves ID to name using name resolution mechanisms like directly from /etc/passwd, /etc/group or through NSS, NSCD etc. `id` command additionally does `getgid` and `getgroups` as well. So these commands work on Android as expected and - along with other similar tools `logname` and `groups` - are part of [toybox](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/toybox/+/refs/heads/master/toys/posix/id.c); Android's choice for all-in-one Linux command line tool.
Bionic libc's [wrapper functions](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/heads/master/libc/SYSCALLS.TXT#34) (that apps actaully use through Android APIs to get UID) and kernel syscalls are also identical as is the case with other libc's:

```
~# nm -C /system/lib64/libc.so | grep geteuid$
0000000000070d58 T geteuid
~# grep geteuid$ /proc/kallsyms
0000000000000000 T sys_geteuid
```

**RELATED:** [HOW TO SETUP LINUX LOGIN ENVIRONMENT ON ANDROID](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209919/218526)