# How to make file executable and belong to my user on Android (rooted phone)

Tags: root-access, magisk

I've put an executable into my /sdcard folder, and here it is:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 root everybody   4128608 2022-05-28 18:46 hello_world
```

it belongs to root. I tried

```
citrus:/sdcard $ chown citrus:citrus hello_world                                                  
chown: bad user 'citrus'
```

`su` and then `chmod +x hello_world` but nothing changes.

How can I make this executable and belong to a normal user, whoever this mioght be.

Android 11 Poco M3

Comment: Move your binary to `/data/local/tmp/` and set permissions there. For `chown` and `chmod` read [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208927/218526). For understanding users concept on Android read the second paragraph [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218572/218526). For more details see [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208982/218526) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209053/218526).